# Number of possible combination of test cases to cover MC DC

Tags: testing, code-coverage, mc-dc

I am trying to understand how to design tests cases to cover the following expression: `Z := (A and not B) or (C xor D);`

Is the following combination the only minimal solution covering MC/DC?

```
   testCaseNO  1 2 3 4 5
      Input A  T T F F F 
      Input B  T F T T T 
      Input C  F F F F T 
      Input D  F F F T F 
     Output Z  F T F T T
```

Or below given also Works fine for MCDC ?

```
   testCaseNO  1 2 3 4 5
      Input A  T T T F F 
      Input B  T F T T F 
      Input C  F F T F T 
      Input D  F F T T T 
     Output Z  F T F T F
```

Comment: I recommend the interesting page and program that can generate a minimum set of MC/DC test cases: https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the second one works for MCDC.  You do not demostrate that Input A independently affects the output.  In test case 1, A is T and output Z is F.  In test case 4 A is F, input D also changes.  So you don't know which one changes the output to T.

Comment: Thanks a lot finally i understand that i miss understood the concept of MCDC..

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your examples satisfies MC/DC.

To evaluate whether test cases satisfy MC/DC, a good approach is to pair up test cases, so that each pair:

- Differs only in one value
- Gives different results

There should be one such pair for every condition. So, for the first example:

- case 1 and case 3 toggles A, *but does not produce a different result*
- case 1 and case 2 toggles B, producing a different result
- case 3 and case 5 toggles C, producing a different result
- case 3 and case 4 toggles D, producing a different result

In the second example, the only pair that changes a single input value is cases 1 and 2. All other pairs change two or more values.

A test set that does provide full MC/DC in this case is:

```
test case No 1 2 3 4 5
Input A      T T F F F
Input B      T F F F F
Input C      F F F T F
Input D      F F F F T
Output Z     F T F T T
```

- A is satisfied by 2 and 3
- B is satisfied by 1 and 2
- C is satisfied by 3 and 4
- D is satisfied by 3 and 5

Comment: If I test this MC/DC for the following: (A and B') or (C or D); it satisfies it perfectly. Do not we need this MC/DC happen to work for that specific expression? Because this coverage covers the given expression yes; but also covers additional expression, such as my example.

Comment: The test set I've given above **does not** provide 100% MC/DC for the decision: `(A and B) or (C or D)` - unlike the above A is **not** satisfied by 2 and 3 (both test cases give a false result).

The principle you are asking about is correct: it is possible to have one set of inputs satisfy two different expressions. The simplest form of this is tests for `(A or B)` and also `(A xor B)`  where you can have TF FT and FF.

Comment: I meant "B not", not B (oh my). Thanks for your answer, it was not clear. I thought a MC/DC should satisfy every condition "just" for that example, but I think the safe way is just to test every possible condition there is, if we are talking about a really critical system.